# Cant get array from spring to angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a basic angular2/spring website. 
My goal is to get array of products form my spring backend;

This is how I import the data in my angular component:

```
 this.http.get<Produkt[]>('/get-produkty').subscribe(data => this.produkty = data);
```

where http is instance of HttpClient.

produkt interface:

```
 interface Produkt { nazwa: string; typ:string; cena:number;}
```

My spring method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-produkty")
public Produkt[] getNames() {
    return  dao.getProduktyAsTab();
}
```

produkty is arrayList of type Produkt, I'm trying to convert it to Array.
It works fine as long as I convert my list to array like this:

```
public Produkt[] getProduktyAsTab() {
    Produkt[] produktyTest = new Produkt[10];
    this.produkty.toArray(produktyTest);
    return produktyTest;
}
```

But it doesn't when I try to do it like this:

```
public Produkt[] getProduktyAsTab() {
    Produkt[] produktyTest = (Produkt[]) this.produkty.toArray();
    return produktyTest;
}
```

I receive response code 500.

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/get-produkty", ok: false…}

How do I fix that? Why is this happening?

Comment: What error do you get by spring?

Comment: Spring's jackson mapper should automatically cast any list in spring as a json array. Have you tried to return the list as is?

Comment: Thanks a lot LookForAngular. Now I'm returning the list and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this.produkty is not castable to Produkt[] and you are getting class cast error.